# Firefox clip-path CSS code does not accept

Tags: css, firefox, clip

I am trying to build a round cycle avatar in my website. However, the `clip-path` cycles works for Chrome, Safari and IE9. I do not know why it does not work with Firefox. I am using Firefox 28.0.

My Chrome browser:

[image: Chrome]

Firefox: 
[image]

My CSS code:

```
.author-avatar img{
  height: 41px;
  left: -18px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(50%, 50%, 30%);
  -moz-clip-path: circle(50%, 50%, 30%);
  clip-path: circle(50%, 50%, 30%);
}
```

Is a way to make the firefox looks the same?

Comment: Frankly I'm surprised it's working in Chrome. It's an **experimental**  css property that isn't ready for general use quite yet.

Comment: Oh, really. Does another way to make the firefox looks like chrome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the circle image you can try adding the following to your css:

```
border-radius: 50%;
```